# PaypalExpress not redirecting

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

There have been multiple changes to my **Magento installation** over the past few months, and one of them has caused the `PaypalExpress` button to redirect to the checkout - rather than to `Paypal`.

I've installed a backup of the installation on another server to it is working fine on there (backup is from 4 months ago)

The main changes are making the site fully `HTTPS` and also installation of patch `SUPEE-9767`.

I'm not expecting anybody to tell me exactly what is wrong here, but what would be my **best approach for debugging this** and finding out exactly where the system decides to redirect to `Paypal` or not.

In my limited debugging, I've found out that I don't enter the `startAction()` method in the paypal controller, but that is as far as I could get.

Comment: You  PaypalExpress button case  is not in the checkout process, it is on the shopping cart page or product detail page?

Comment: It is on the product detail page, so it should go straight to Paypal after adding the product to the basket

Comment: You do not need to add the product to the basket, you should click the PaypalExpress button directly.  If you add  product to basket, it absolutely redirect to checkout. That is the default logic. If you have made changes for this logic, you should debug Mage_Checkout_CartControlle->addAction().